# Is there any affinity between IP subnets and DNS domains?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip

I understand what DNS and name servers do.  But one question that I have is whether there are any technical, or convention oriented, relationships between DNS domains and IP address space.

Specifically, if I have a domain like chad.com with hosts like:

a.chad.com
b.chad.com
c.chad.com

Are there any constraint on the IP addresses that can be mapped to the hosts in that domain?  Or could I do the following:

a = 10.5.200.1
b = 192.168.0.55
c = 118.23.22.1

A bit rookie here, so feel free to point out any glaring fundamental misteps in my reasoning.

Comment: Well, `a` and `b` are private (RFC 1918) addresses and using them would work only within a private network, but other than that it's entirely possible.

Comment: Q: Is there any affinity between IP subnets and DNS domains? A: No there isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really shouldn't be any reason you can't do that. If that is where your server's are, then that is where they are, DNS doesn't really care much.

Comment: The only caveat is that most consider it bad form to point your domain to hosts which are not operated by you, nor are performing services for you.